# Why cannot my xml file in the artifact recognize the mappings?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, servlets

I have a maven web project in IntelliJ, with Tomcat server, and I have a web.xml file in the WEB-INF folder. The project works well locally. But when I package this into war and deploy it to Heroku, I get an error saying that there is no xml found. And I get a 404 error (not sure if related.) I know the lack of an xml is not an error message, but the xml contains important information. How could this be?

In development I have been using war-exploded. When I look in this folder, the web.xml sits right there, and the content is the same as the one in development. Now, deploying it to Heroku, I am trying two methods: 1. I use IntelliJ's integration with Heroku; 2. I deploy the project in Heroku from Github. In both circumstances, I get similar errors.

In the first attempt, I added the following to my POM file:
war

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>app-name</appName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then I run Heroku:deploy-war, and it says that webxml is lacking. If I force to ignore this, everything crashes immediately. During the process, a war file is created automatically under the target folder.

In the second attempt, I added a Procfile with the following:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT 
target/app-name.war
```

And I added the following to my POM file:

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>9.0.41.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then I deploy it from Git in Heroku. There is a message saying that there is no xml found. The app is up, but I get 404 pages when I request resources.

I am considering deploying the war locally and see if I can get more information.

Comment: What XML is this? Is it web.xml? How do you build the WAR file? Using Maven? Something else? Have you looked inside the WAR file to see if your file is in there, at the correct location and with the expected content? Do you have any server errors when running your application? You have to provide more details than what you wrote in your question otherwise people can't help you

Comment: This suggests to me that your WAR isn't being created correctly.  You should open the WAR and prove to yourself that it is identical in every way to the exploded WAR that runs successfully in IntelliJ.  I would recommend that you try Spring Boot.  You won't need Tomcat anymore.  You'll have an executable JAR file that runs on a JVM.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am putting in more details now. Although the web works locally, I get some red letters during deployment, most of which are illegible characters, which is why I did not deal with them. But you reminded me that this could be the root problem. Part of the messages  says "org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory" "org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars" What should I do next?

Comment: OK. I'm now trying to move everything to a new project by Spring boot.

Comment: @JaneR: before doing anything else, I suggest you look at the generated WAR file. Unpack it and look inside of it to see everything is as expected. From what you are describing, the WAR might be wrong. The WAR is a ZIP file so rename it with a ZIP extension, unzip it and look inside.

Comment: @Bogdan: I did as you said, and indeed I saw no WEB-INF folder inside. And as I mentioned just now, even the exploded war shows error messages which seem to point to a missing DD. Strangely, the WEB-INF folder sits in the "out/artifacts/app-name_Web_exploded" folder as well as in the "web" folder for my development. Probably I need to configure somewhere in the project structure or the run configuration?

Comment: You should probably look at the documentation for the maven-war-plugin. You can build a WAR file without web.xml if you use newer versions of the Servlet API (from 3.0 up) where you can do with annotations what you can do with web.xml. But if you need web.xml you need to make sure it's packed in the WAR. Look at the maven-war-plugin documentation and look for any errors during packing of the WAR file

Comment: I mean my web.xml seems to be ignored even before I had to use that maven-war-plugin. But your first suggestion seems to be helpful. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for similar problems here, I realized that I lost my web.xml in the war file because it is a maven project and I should put it in src/main/webapp folder, instead of a web folder. After copying my project to another one with maven-webapp archetype, I was able to include the web.xml file in my war file and successfully deploy my project.